# Kotlin java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:448

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am learning Kotlin but my computer so bad to use Intellij. I downladed VSCODE and I followed all steps. I mean Code Runner, Kotlin Language extension and add to path. But when I run to code any code. Like this

```
fun fun main(args: Array<String>) {
print("Hello")
}
```

Vscode return this message

```
exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 448
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(ClassReader.java:2464)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(ClassReader.java:2525)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:761)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:646)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:507)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.modules.JavaModuleInfo$Companion.read(JavaModuleInfo.kt:67)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:44)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder.access$findSystemModule(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:37)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.modules.CliJavaModuleFinder$systemModules$1.invoke(CliJavaModuleFinder.kt:25)
at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:149)
at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.calcNext(Sequences.kt:109)
at kotlin.sequences.FilteringSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:133)
at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.ensureItemIterator(Sequences.kt:254)
at kotlin.sequences.FlatteningSequence$iterator$1.hasNext(Sequences.kt:241)
at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.none(_Sequences.kt:1239)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.addModularRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:227)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.computeRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:124)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.convertClasspathRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:79)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:230)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:114)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:409)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:286)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createEnvironmentWithScriptingSupport(K2JVMCompiler.kt:276)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:196)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:109)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:53)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:70)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMainNoExit(CLITool.kt:157)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool$Companion.doMain(CLITool.kt:148)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler$Companion.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt:343)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.main(K2JVMCompiler.kt)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.run(Preloader.java:81)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader.main(Preloader.java:43)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Java version do you use? Try `java -version` to see that. You may probably need Java 11 (or 8). Also, I see `fun fun` in the code snippet, probably a typoe

I found that related issue for that
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21303

Try using the fresh version of Kotlin compiler, e.g. `1.3.21`

Comment: java 10 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)

Comment: java 10 2018-03-20

Comment: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)

Comment: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)

Comment: You have a pre-release java version, please upgrade to Java 11 LTS release

Comment: Thanks I will update.But I try to Mac laptop and its works.My teachers laptop.I thought it could be path manager.Because we adjust windows systems path but mac unix based so problem related to path.

Comment: It should just work in IntelliJ Community. I assume it has the most advanced support for Kotlin too

Comment: Thanks mr Eugene.I guess it should be

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating your kotlin version. I had the same issue with the error below using Intellij. I updated Kotlin plugin from a version 1.2. something to 1.3.11 and the hello world code was able to run.

```
Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10883
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort
(ClassReader.java:2464)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(ClassReader.java:2525)
at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:761)
.......
```